# Android build.gradle fail Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I program with Android Studio.

Error message:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexRelease'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

And my `build.grandle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "theToolcome.theTool.theTool"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'
}
```

I didn't change anything, I only added the Google analytics. What's my problem? I search also on the stackoverflow, but nothing worked for me.

I also imported the project again, but nothing helped me.

Comment: Please add some information what you have tried, Cleaning your project and rebuilding, ...

Comment: @BojanKseneman yes i rebuild and build and clean my project

Comment: Do you know how to build from the console?

Comment: @BojanKseneman whats is better to build from the console ?

Comment: You could run the build with --info flag that will display in more details what is wrong and you could post that here so we would get some more detailed information on what is wrong. It could be you reached 65k methods or it could be something else

Comment: @BojanKseneman ist this command wright : gradlew.bat assembleRelease  ?

Comment: gradew.bat assembleDebug --info

Comment: @BojanKseneman 

D:\Apps\theTool>gradew.bat assembleDebug --info
'gradew.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Hmm, it doesn't work

Comment: It does work, but you have to be in the directory with your project. As you can see, I have no errors. C:\android\studio_workspace\UIFake>gradlew.bat assembleDebug --info
Connected to daemon DaemonInfo{pid=5040 ...

Comment: @BojanKseneman yes, im in the directory but doesn't work yet

i know now , that this line is the problem :
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'

Comment: So how did you fix it? :D

Comment: @BojanKseneman first i used the tutorial from [Tutplus.com/Android-Analytics-Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-enabling-google-analytics-to-gather-app-statistics--mobile-6607) but i forgot to delete the jar file....

Comment: I have posted the results in an answer below.

Answer (score 4):

For everyone reading.

The problem was that he downloaded a sample from the internet that contained anaylitics jar file, and he also told Android Studio to compile it for him via `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'` so the end effect was that there were two libraries with mostly the same classes and that failed the build.

Answer (score 2):

As the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) states out, your applications method references have exceeded the maximum limit:

> Note: If the number of method references in your app exceeds the 65K limit, your app may fail to compile. You may be able to mitigate this problem when compiling your app by specifying only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses, instead of all of them. For information on how to do this, see Selectively compiling APIs into your executable.

Instead of importing the entire Google Play Services, you should import the part that you use.

So instead of `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'` you could use `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.3.0'`, if what you want is GoogleMap API.

Check the [Analytical Table](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#split) and select the part that you want, then import it and you should be fine.

Comment: but i want to use the "Google Analytics API" i can't replace the google analytics api with the google maps api ?

Comment: I see what's the problem. What emulator do you use?

Comment: i use no emulator, i use my sony xperia Z1, but i can't build my app.

Comment: Have you installed the google play services from the sdk? You can check it by going on *SDK Manager* in Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

Project structure > JDK Location > Change it to a 1.7 version of the jdk.

Answer (score 0):

In your message log you can scroll down to errors there  can you see what the error is and maybe you can solve it at yourself. Otherwise one of the forum members can maybe help if you send the error.